# Android activity views changes their display z-order to opposite after onPause-onResume

Tags: android, android-layout, android-lifecycle

I have the layout with 3 views, which are situated one over another to implement z-order:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <view
        android:id="@+id/above"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        class="com.hooliganslab.stormx.VSurfaceView"
    />

    <view
        android:id="@+id/gl_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.hooliganslab.stormx.GLNativeSurfaceView"
    />

    <view
        android:id="@+id/below"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        class="com.hooliganslab.stormx.VSurfaceView"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code of onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
    setContentView(R.layout.sandwich);
    _above=(VSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.above);
    _gl_view=(GLNativeSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.gl_view);
    _below=(VSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.below);
    _handler = new Handler();
    _pause=false;
}
```

The code of onResume:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    _gl_view.onResume();
    _pause=false;
    render();
}
```

The code of onPause:

```
protected void onPause() {
    _gl_view.onPause();
    _pause=true;
    super.onPause();        
}
```

When application started (onCreate-onResume) view identified as "below" lies below of view identified as gl_view, view identified as "above" lies above of view identified as gl_view.

When application reappeared after pause (onPause-onResume) views changes their display order to opposite: view identified as "above" lies below of view identified as gl_view, view identified as "below" lies above of view identified as gl_view. This order then remains steadily despite the further switching.

This behavior does not depend on the type of used layout (RelativeLayout or FrameLayout) nor wrapping views into LinearLayouts.

If I call setZOrderMediaOverlay(true) for gl_view, it always lies over both "above" and "below" views.

What should I do to create a proper and permanent order of views?

Important! The words "Above" and "below" are used here in the sense of z-order.

Comment: can you please share your code of the activity or fragment you call these views in?

Comment: The codes of onCreate-onResume-onPause are added.

Comment: I change layout parameters (topMargin, leftMatgin, width and height) of view "above" or "below" in my code. Then I bind MediaPlayer to selected view in its onLayout procedure. This code is more specific but I could add it too if this will be useful for understanding the problem.

Comment: what does render() do?

Comment: render() starts gl_view native renderer calls periodically by timer